Inverse Laplace transform and residues.
$u(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}u(s)=\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \mathrm{e}^{st} \mathcal{L}u(s)\,ds,\quad t\geq 0$
$u(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}u(s)=\sum_{s \text{ in poles } } \text{Residues}(\mathrm{e}^{st}\mathcal{L}u(s))$
Question 1. The inverse Laplace transform can be always computed with the residues of the integrand? or not?
thanks.

By the definition of the Laplace, and the inverse, it should be. This does not mean it will always be easy to do so.
